# Purpose of cc to self

Tags: productivity, email

I noticed that some people inculde themselves in "cc" when they send out an email. What is the reason for this? A quick search on google showed that several people want to learn how to be able to do this automatically.

Comment: Because Outlook doesn't work like Gmail.

Comment: Outlook 2010 added that feature.  It will show all related emails in the chain including ones that you sent.

Comment: Is this causing you problems?  Right now you are asking for a list of reasons for doing something.  That is not very constructive.

Comment: @David Unfortunately (at least with an Exchange inbox), enabling conversation view resulted in lagging and jerky scrolling in the messages list.

Comment: To make outlook work like gmail (by arranging the emails as conversations - no need to go to sent items) & to choke the company internet bandwidth !!!

Comment: I use a self-CC when I'm BCCing multiple people.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Most people I know that exhibit this behavior is so they have an email in their inbox that continues the chain, and they can see their response in the timeline continuity of the chain.  If you don't CC yourself, most email clients do not show your response, as it goes to the "Sent" folder, and does not appear in your Inbox or the same folder the email chain is in.

Answer (score 10):

We tend to have multiple projects live at any given time. We use subject headers like:

> [Project A]: Discussion on blah

I set up rules in Outlook where if an email contains "Project A" in the subject, it should be routed to the "Project A" folder in my inbox. When I CC myself in these emails, I can be sure that my "Project A" folder contains all related emails, including those that I sent.

It also means that I can periodically clear out my Sent Mails folder without worrying about losing project specific emails.

Comment: If it's a very particular use case how does it answer the question?

Comment: I find it useful to keep emails and reports segregated by Project in my inbox. It is a way in which I use CC-ing myself in the email. I think it is relevant to the question since the OP asks why people CC themselves in an email.

Comment: @enderland, maybe you can explain how you think it doesn't answer the question. The question was what is the reason people use CC, and Luhar explained why. I think this is clear, but if you disagree, maybe providing more/better feedback can help Luhar improve this post. Hope this helps.

Comment: @jmort253 I just don't think an answer where someone specifically says their answer applies to a "very particular use-case" can even remotely be considered a generalizable answer to this question. The point of SE isn't to see how many obscure and specific situations we can get, it's to answer a question. Lots of answers like this one do NOT answer the question because there are millions of specific reasons people do this.

Comment: @enderland - Does my edit fix the problem? What about the other answers? Aren't they sort of listing specific uses as well?  1. See responses without going to sent mail.  2. Using it as a task management system.  Let's not get too lost in keywords, especially when removing them can easily fix the problem. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 7):

Some people use their email inbox (and sometimes other tools in their email client, such as Outlook's Todo list) to manage work tasks in a central location. In this case, putting emails that indicate that something requires action (a task, something to follow up on, etc.) in their inbox is a way to make it more visible than in their sent items folder. Adding a CC to themselves immediately puts the item as unread in their inbox until they process it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I only CC myself when I need to create a "paper trail." Most of the time it is sufficient to wait for the other person's reply before I think about the thread again, but if I find that the other person is being unresponsive or if I need to follow up if the other person does not respond in a certain amount of time I will CC myself. Once I have CC'd myself it is easier to reply to myself later and anyone reading the thread later can see the gap in response between my two emails. Usually people see this happening and want to reply so that it does not look like they are the problem.